# Change the name of duplicated events in #region "Event implementation for <interface>" for Xamarin Android Binding library

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm attempting to create a Xamarin Binding Library for the [Android UseButton library](https://github.com/button/button-android). I created my binding project, included the .aar and set Build Action = LibraryProjectZip. As was expected, a bunch of errors popped up and I've managed to get rid of most using the Metadata.xml file, except for a bunch that follow the same pattern:

> Error CS0102  The type 'CrossBridgeCommunicator' already contains a definition for 'WebViewDismiss'

I checked the CrossBridgeCommunicator class, and found it has 2 copies of about 12 events. Here's a snippet of one of these duplicates

```
#region "Event implementation for Com.Usebutton.Sdk.Internal.Bridge.BridgeMessageParser.IListener"
...
public event EventHandler WebViewDismiss {
    add {
        global::Java.Interop.EventHelper.AddEventHandler<global::Com.Usebutton.Sdk.Internal.Bridge.BridgeMessageParser.IListener, global::Com.Usebutton.Sdk.Internal.Bridge.BridgeMessageParser.IListenerImplementor>(
        ref weak_implementor___SetMainBridge,
        __CreateIListenerImplementor,
        __v => MainBridge = __v,
        __h => __h.OnWebViewDismissHandler += value);
    }
...
}
...
public event EventHandler WebViewDismiss {
    add {
        global::Java.Interop.EventHelper.AddEventHandler<global::Com.Usebutton.Sdk.Internal.Bridge.BridgeMessageParser.IListener, global::Com.Usebutton.Sdk.Internal.Bridge.BridgeMessageParser.IListenerImplementor>(
        ref weak_implementor___SetWidgetBridge,
        __CreateIListenerImplementor,
        __v => WidgetBridge = __v,
        __h => __h.OnWebViewDismissHandler += value);
    }
...
}
```

The only difference between them is that they access different attributes in their bodies (the "weak_implementor__"). I checked the original class in a Java decompiler and it doesn't implement any of these events; in fact, it doesn't even implement the interface. What it does have are 2 fields of this interface type. I'm guessing Xamarin creates these methods for some reason, but I don't know why or how. They don't even appear on the api.xml (nor do the fields).

I tried to change the name of the events using the Metadata.xml file, but, since these events don't even exist in the Java class, I don't know how to find them. I even tried to remove the fields using "remove-node", but am getting the warning no nodes matched. Does anyone know how can I change these events' names? Again, they come from the same interface, but are created directly on the class that has 2 fields of the interface type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is because there is some conflict between event types that come from more than one interface type that shares methods having identical names. To avoid this, you can try to use some metadata transformation.For more, check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings#problem-duplicate-custom-eventargs-types .

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but, as I said on my question, if I use the Metadata.xml I end up affecting both duplicates, since their signatures are exactly the same. The example you linked doesn't apply here because the duplicate properties have a different signature (e.g. different class names); in my case, the duplicated events come from the same interface and appear out of nowhere.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem?

Comment: @undermind I ended up removing the whole class with remove-node. It didn't reem to create any problems at compile time, but the project was handed off to someone else, so I don't know if this will fix the problem completely. Hope it helps!

Comment: I didn't find a reason why these events are placed into the class that doesn't implement the corresponding interfaces, but I managed to fix the problem by renaming the events with the following rule <attr path="/api/package[@name='package_name']/interface[@name='interface_name']/method[@name='old_conflicting_name']" name="managedName">new_unique_name</attr>